# C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log

Tags: python

I tried the code below, but got the warn message in the log:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered
```

What is this? And how can I solve this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-np.e, np.e, 100)

plt. plot(x, np.exp(x), '-')

plt. plot(x, np.log(x), '-')

plt.legend(('y=e^x', 'y=lnx'))
plt. xlabel('x')
plt. ylabel('y')

a = plt.gca()
a.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
a.spines['left'].set_position('zero')

a.spines['top'].set_color('None')
a.spines['right'].set_color('None')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You put a negative value into the function `log()` (logarithm).  That's mathematically not defined and for this you get the error message.

Maybe you want `x = np.linspace(0, np.e, 100)`.  For `0` the `np.log()` returns `-inf` which might raise problems later but at least not at this point.

Otherwise let your interval start at `1e-40` or similar.  For this `no.log()` will return decent values (like -50 or similar).